# How to crop a Mat to ROI in Emgu (OpenCV for C#)

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, emgucv

Some of the answers I found recommended using :

```
frame = ...
Rectangle ROI = ...
Mat crop = new Mat(frame, ROI)
```

But this does not seem to wokr in Emgu 3.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. To crop a Mat, you have to use an Image object as a buffer and use its .ROI property:

```
Mat crop_color_frame(Mat input, Rectangle crop_region)
{
  /*
   * TODO(Ahmed): Figure out why I had to copy this into this class.
   * */
  Image<Bgr, Byte> buffer_im = input.ToImage<Bgr, Byte>();
  buffer_im.ROI = crop_region;

  Image<Bgr, Byte> cropped_im = buffer_im.Copy();


  return cropped_im.Mat;

}
```

Comment: Hi, I am stuck with this. After I get Mat myNewMat = new Mat(input, crop_region);
I am not able to save it with VideoWriter like writer.Write(myNewMat);

Answer (score 7):

Ahmed, you really do not have to create an Image<> just to create a Mat. Try the following:

```
Mat myNewMat = new Mat(input, crop_region);
```

Since you do not have a RotatedRect you do not have to translate the rotated rectangle into an upright rectangle. So you can just create a new Mat from your existing Mat and the rectangle.

This should work and can simplify your code some.

Doug

Answer (score 0):

Ahmed, what doesn't work? Are you not getting a Mat with the data? What is "frame" is "frame" a Mat? Is your ROI by chance a RotatedRect? Because you are right if you are using a RotatedRect that won't work. If frame is a Mat then what you are doing should work just fine. Need some details about what is not working.

Comment: It was just a syntax error, but I found the correct method for cropping frames in C#.